# Multibit error message

Tags: multibit

Upon opening multibit I get this error message; any idea what it means?

"[Det gick inte att läsa](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Det%20gick%20inte%20att%20l%C3%A4sa%20in) in https://multibit.org/version.txt. [Felet var](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Felet%20var) javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target."

Answer (score 1):

It is an error to do with getting hold of a 'new version available' file from multibit.org. It means you won't get notification of new MultiBit versions but can otherwise be ignored.

Some versions of Java have problems with the HTTPS certificate on multibit.org.

I am going to change how the version.txt file is authenticated which will make this error disappear.